# Standard way of marking a github organization or repository as deprecated?

Tags: git, github, npm

There's a [issue filed here from 2014](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/144) suggesting an option for marking a github repository as deprecated.  Anyone know if there's a way to do this besides placing a big deprecated banner in the readme?  Ideally it would also work for an entire organization.  Marking the organization as deprecated would cascade to all child repositories.

There does exist a [Current best practice for “retiring” a project on github and npmjs.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457959/current-best-practice-for-retiring-a-project-on-github-and-npmjs-org) but I'm looking for a standard way to do this that changes the icon or text in the list of repos (strikeout?), and adds a "deprecated" background image, as well as a hook that would trigger a deprecation of the corresponding NPM repo.  As I mentioned, it should also trigger deprecation for all repositories contained in an organization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Current best practice for "retiring" a project on github and npmjs.org?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457959/current-best-practice-for-retiring-a-project-on-github-and-npmjs-org)

Answer (score 4):

Until a new feature is added do the following

1. Edit the README.md
2. Change the title (emojis work here)

> :no_entry: [DEPRECATED] Active at https://github.com/{user}/{newproject}

3. Add two topics

> deprecated / obsolete

Comment: This can be closed. Github added an archive feature. See: https://github.com/blog/2460-archiving-repositories

Answer (score 0):

For an organization, I would suggest making a script which automatically changes the description for each repository in the organization, and adds the content that [DaJudge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5694003/dajudge) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45670785/1166929). There's no current way of automatically deprecating an entire organization using GitHub.

I don't understand what you mean by a background image. I've been changing the title of the README itself to `# DEPRECATED`. Are you suggesting adding an image in to make it clear, too?

Comment: Yes - An image that is added automatically by a service or by github (Perhaps a github application) - that displays a faded deprecated banner in the background of the home page for the project's README.  It should have an "UNDER CONSTRUCTION / RESTAURANT CLOSED" type feel to it.